# Gem and NPM temp/cache directories safe to delete?

Tags: node.js, npm, rubygems, homebrew

I'm using homebrew for my management of Ruby Gems and Node/NPM. I've tried to keep everything in homebrew's default path of /usr/local. However there are still some directories being created in my $HOME and I'd like to know if it is safe to delete them?

```
~/.bundle
~/.config
~/.gem
~/.npm
```

Comment: Well, you could move them somewhere; check if it breaks things; then either move them back or delete them.

Comment: ~/.config is a general config directory used by many applications. You probably should not remove this one.

Comment: Also check what’s in them. E.g. my `~/.bundle` only contains a `cache` directory but yours might be different.

Comment: Sledgehammer testing, I like it @bfontaine :)